# MS Windows what are the different F5/refresh

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

I work with a bunch of windows developers and our app is a web application.  I was often told I need to "refresh" my windows, and it seems there are many ways to "refresh", and each has a different function (refresh cache, reload javascript, etc, etc).  I was told to:

```
- press F5 or right click refresh
- Ctrl-F5, Shift-F5, Ctrl+Shift-F5 (no alt-F5 yet ;-)) or
- right click, then shift+refresh, ctrl+refresh, ctrl+shift+refresh
```

Ok, I am confused!  Can someone please shed some light to this?  Where can I find a definitive list of meaning for the different F5/refresh combinations.  I researched but yield no good answer...

Thanks in advance!

Sorry, I should have mentioned it is for IE9 or 10

Comment: `CTRL+F5` is the default shortcut to refresh web content in all the major browsers on Windows and/or the contents of an explorer window.

Comment: I've never had to do anything more than `F5`, nothing more complicated than that, but when you're dealing with a custom application that someone built, you'd have to speak with them. If I wanted to I could map the `J` key to be refresh in an application.

Comment: Thanks everyone!

It looks like it is either F5 or Ctrl-F5 for reload or hard reload.

Answer (score 3):

The answer would depend on the browser being used. And as such, the browser's documentation should shed some light into the keys used.

For Firefox, there is the following [post](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly).

- Navigation:

  - Reload: <kbd>F5</kbd> OR <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
  - Reload (override cache): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> OR <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

According to [this](http://www-jo.se/f.pfleger/firefox-reload) site, the main difference between reloading and reloading (overriding cache) (described as *hard reload* next) are the following:

> - **load**: no request happens until the cached resource expires
> - **reload**: the request contains the If-Modified-Since and Cache-Control: max-age=0 headers that allow the server to respond with 304 Not Modified if applicable
> - **hard reload**: the request contains the Pragma: no-cache and Cache-Control: no-cache headers and will bypass the cache

For IE there's [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-is/windows7/internet-explorer-keyboard-shortcuts) post. Quoting:

- Refresh the current webpage: <kbd>F5</kbd>
- Refresh the current webpage, even if the time stamp for the web version and your locally stored version are the same (equals to override cache): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the browser or application being used.

With web browsers, usually it's <kbd>F5</kbd> for a page refresh of (just) the HTML, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to force a full refresh (CSS, JavaScript, etc. are also re-downloaded, regardless of cache time-stamps).